# Sharing Alternation Index

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to implement odd-even style to my listbox but for every row I have three different nested listboxes so I need to share the alternation index between them.

I've put a picture of my application, as you can see if one list ends with an odd row and other one starts with an odd row, it looks weird.

Thanks.

[image: Odd-Even Alternation Index]

Comment: Create your own alternation converter.  Its not that hard.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't really know where to start with it?

Comment: http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/AlternationConverter@cs/1305600/AlternationConverter@cs has the source.  You can see how incredibly easy it is to create an IValueConverter that converts an int into a color within an indexed collection.  You just need to keep some internal state within your converter, or use some kind of converter parameter to control this.